# Getting mysql table data in php using class

Tags: php, mysql

hi I am trying to make a small php application like a gridview, the code given below is working but I want that the column name should be changed during the creation of instance of that class

```
<?php
class datasource
{
public $cell;
function __construct($sql,$my)
{
    if($my===false)
    {
        die("error: Could not connect ot the server".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
        if($result = $my->query($sql))
        {
            if($result->num_rows>0)
            {
                echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
                while($row=$result->fetch_array())
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    $this->getname();
                                       //echo "<td>".$row['OrderID']."</td>";  working
                               echo "<td>".$row[$this->cell]."</td>"; // at this line undefined index is shown
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                $result->close();
            }
            else
            {
                die("error No Records Found");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            die("error");
        }
    }
}//function connect

  }

 ?>

 <?php

  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","9889922527","demo");
   if($mysqli===false)
    {
die("error".mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  else
 {
$sql = "select * from `order`"; 
$n = new datasource($sql,$mysqli);
    $n->cell = 'OrderID';
var_dump($n->cell);
  }
   $mysqli->close();

  ?>
```

in the given code no data is displayed and undefined index warning is shown

Comment: which warning you get ?

Comment: In your class you use undefined $this->cell. Fix it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are defining cell value after calling query through constructor.

create another function in class to do query.
Then define cell value efore calling sql function.

```
function __construct($sql,$my)
```

replace this line with following

```
function sqlFn($sql,$my)
```

And then

```
$n = new datasource($sql,$mysqli);
$n->cell = 'OrderID';
```

replace above as following

```
$n = new datasource();
$n->cell = 'OrderID';
$n->sqlFn($sql,$mysqli);
```